# Is there any way to implement a custom stream decoder in a pdf document?

Tags: pdf, stream, customization, decode

I want to implement a custom stream decode filter for inclusion in a PDF. The stream will have been encoded from a series of line instructions (x y l) generated by a function that emits hundreds or thousands of such instructions drawing lines within a few pixels of each other (output from mathematical graphic functions). The encoding compressor (not within the PDF) can reduce the size of such stream to less than a tenth of the size of the uncompressed stream, but will require a complementary decoder (in place of the standards like FlateDecode). So how can such a custom decoding function be included within a PDF file?

Comment: It can not. At least not in an interoperable manner. (Unless your encoding is actually not new but already specified in the pdf standard...)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does 'interoperable' mean, or what's different from non-interoperable? 
I was hoping JavaScript could somehow be applied.

Comment: 'Interoperable' means 'supported by a wide range of PDF processors'. JavaScript, by the way, is supported only by some PDF viewers and by a even lower fraction of the non-viewer PDF processors.

Comment: The encode/decode process is done by the viewer, you can't put the function in the PDF. You'd need to create a custom viewer or you'd need to limit your PDF viewers to ones that support plugins (Acrobat, Foxit, and a few others) and then develop a plugin for each viewer to do the decoding.

Comment: Thank you both.  I've come to realize the inability to include custom processors must be due to protection of the security from malware.

Comment: Might there be an avenue for establishing additional safe decoding methods?